# Xcode 7 Archive Error with static libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

> Ld /Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyDoctorFinder.build/Release-iphoneos/MyDoctorFinder.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyDoctorFinder normal armv7
>       cd /Users/purplebug/Documents/MyDoctorFinder/MyDoctorFinder
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/purplebug/Documents/MyDoctorFinder/MyDoctorFinder -F/Users/purplebug/Documents/MyDoctorFinder/MyDoctorFinder/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -filelist /Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyDoctorFinder.build/Release-iphoneos/MyDoctorFinder.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyDoctorFinder.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -ObjC -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework GoogleMaps -framework Accelerate -framework CoreBluetooth -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -lz -licucore -lc++ -framework ImageIO -framework GLKit -framework CoreText -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreData -framework AVFoundation -framework MessageUI -lsqlite3 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyDoctorFinder.build/Release-iphoneos/MyDoctorFinder.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyDoctorFinder_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/purplebug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDoctorFinder-bjdxztijegnaxobgqvqhbnuqqsin/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyDoctorFinder/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyDoctorFinder.build/Release-iphoneos/MyDoctorFinder.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyDoctorFinder

*ld: could not extract files from bitcode bundle for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

Comment: Do you use your Library as Static ? disable BitCode from your project then make build again

Comment: I'm not really sure of that, for this project was handed over to me just recently. I'll go take a look at your suggestion, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Thank you, disabling BitCode worked.

Comment: your welcome :)
so please mark the answer to help another person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use your Library as Static  ?

disable `BitCode` from your project then make build again